# Quote signs in strings (java)

Tags: java, string, quote

I write a bracket checker in Java and have problems searching for single quotes in the text.
if I have a String like e.g. the following (!in this case it's the text I'm interested not the code):

```
else if (line.charAt(i)=='\''||line.charAt(i)=='\"'){
```

in the debugger I see that after the first equals sign I get the following characters in my String:

```
0 = '

1 = \\\

2 = ' 

3 = '
```

How can I combine 1 and 2 - so that he doesn't read the second ' as ' anymore? I thought it is done with backslash - but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

If the code is of any help: This is how I treat single and double quotes:

```
Stack <Character> theStack = new Stack<Character>();
// loop through file line per line
String line;

else if (line.charAt(i)=='\'' ||line.charAt(i)=='\"'){
   // check whether there is already one of them on top
   if (line.charAt(i)== '\'' && theStack.peek()=='\''){
       theStack.pop();
    }

    else if (line.charAt(i)== '\"' && theStack.peek()=='\"'){
       theStack.pop();
    }
    // else push new one on top
    else {
        theStack.push(line.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

It fails because in the line shown above it reads three single/double quotes. It should read only two of them. I do not understand how I can avoid the Scanner to read the second single/double quote in the statement shown above as a single quote. I thought it is done with backslash.

Comment: How should we know what you are doing wrong without seeing your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your `if` condition as follows

```
else if ((line.charAt(i) == '\'' || line.charAt(i) == '\"')
                               && line.charAt(i-1) != '\\') {
```

This would ignore all quotes that have been escaped with a backslash i.e. should not be treated as a closing quote and pop your character stack. You can further simplify your `if-else` blocks as

```
// check whether there is already one of them on top
if (line.charAt(i) == theStack.peek()) { // un-boxing to char
   theStack.pop();
}
// else push new one on top
else {
    theStack.push(line.charAt(i));
}
```

This works because the parent `else-if` block has already made sure that the line character is either `'` or `"` and so we can go ahead and directly compare it with the head of your character stack.